# vue select component - set defaults props?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, defaults, vue-select

I use this vue-multiselect plugin: https://vue-multiselect.js.org/
Since I'm going to use it many times, I want to set some defaults props.

For example I want the `selectLabel` prop to be an empty string, and maybe to sets some `<slot>`s.

In a typical jQuery plugin I could use `$.plugin.defaults` to set the defaults. How to do the same with vue plugins?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`extends`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#extends) to subclass your component. Pass it a spec just like you would use when defining a component, but only supply the things you want to provide defaults for.

```
<script>
  import Multiselect from 'vue-multiselect';

  export default {
    extends: Multiselect,
    props: {
      selectLabel: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: An example how to use with component?

Comment: Works great. And how can I provide the default slots?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that with `extends`. I think you would have to make a [wrapper component](https://vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html) to specify a template that includes your base component and its slots.

Comment: Can you explain how this will go with `extends` ? it seems to me that I need to override the component template, which I obviously don't want to. And I can't see any convenient way

Comment: That is why I don't think you can do it with `extends`. You need to make a wrapper component.